# Using data attribute on radio button group to show text

Tags: javascript, html, forms, radio-button

The outcome I am after is that when a user sends keyboard focus to a radio button group and navigates to each radio button using the arrow keys, or, clicks a radio button with a pointing device (mouse), the data-attribute value for that radio button is set to an element (h2).

I have got this far , and am now stuck. I am using an ID for the example, however, I would prefer to use a class or the data-set="X".

The code below sets the first data-col value but not the second.

Thanks for any help as I learn so much from Stackoverflow. I need this in vanilla JS and not jQuery, sorry.

```
<p>
<label for="">The colour is Green
<input type="radio" name="bob" data-col="Green" data-set="Green" id="demo3">
</label>
 <label for="">The colour is Blue
<input type="radio" name="bob" data-col="Blue" data-set="Blue" id="demo3">
</label>
</p>
<h2 id="chjkl"></h2>

document.getElementById('demo3').onclick = function changeClk() {
  const setCol = document.querySelector('#demo3');
  document.getElementById('chjkl').innerHTML = setCol.dataset.col

}
document.getElementById('demo3').onfocus = function changeFoc() {
const setCol = document.querySelector('#demo3');
  document.getElementById('chjkl').innerHTML = setCol.dataset.col
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `event.target` to get the dataset.

In the example below I change the color of your `h2` elements background. Note that I am passing the `event` into the ***function*** and calling the ***function*** in the `eventListener`.

Also rather than having two `eventListeners`, I add a ***class*** to the ***radio button*** and then query that using `querySelectorAll()`. Then run the **nodeList** through a loop and check the `event.target` when the ***eventListener*** is fired.

An issue with your code is you have more than one element with the same ID. You should not have more than one element with any unique ID. ID must be unique to only one single element.

```js
let radio = document.querySelectorAll('.radio')
let target = document.getElementById('chjkl')

function changeColor(e) {
  target.style.backgroundColor = e.target.dataset.col
  target.textContent = e.target.dataset.col
}

radio.forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('focus', changeColor)
})
```

```css
#chjkl {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  letter-spacing: 1.3rem;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <label for="">The colour is Green
<input type="radio" name="bob" data-col="Green" class="radio">
</label>
  <label for="">The colour is Red
<input type="radio" name="bob" data-col="Red" class="radio">
</label>
  <label for="">The colour is Blue
<input type="radio" name="bob" data-col="Blue" class="radio">
</label>
  <label for="">The colour is Orange
<input type="radio" name="bob" data-col="Orange" class="radio">
</label>
</p>
<h2 id="chjkl"></h2>
```

Comment: That is great, thank you, so simple. In regards to the unique ID, that is something I am aware of. I only used in this case, because I could not get any other method to work.